# Retrieving array values in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json

My code:

```
$.get('ajax/time_menus.php', {
    shift: $('#shifts').val()
  },
  function(data) {
    //load the array into a test element so we can see what is returned
    $("#test").html(data);

    //set the hour menu
    var startHour = data[0];
    alert(startHour);
    $('#from_hours').val(data[0]);
  });
```

Returns an array like this:`["08","00","AM","11","00","AM"]`

But for some reason the `alert( startHour );` line will throw up an alert of:  `[`

What am I doing wrong?

I am receiving this error with Firebug.

site.com/schedule/ajax/time_menus.php?shift=23
GET http://www.sharingizcaring.com/schedule/ajax/time_menus.php?shift=23

200 OK
        296ms   jquery-1.3.2.js (line 3633)
uncaught exception: [Exception... "Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0" nsresult: "0x80570009 (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS)" location: "JS frame :: http://www.sharingizcaring.com/schedule/js/jquery-1.3.2.js :: anonymous :: line 957" data: no]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because `data` is a string. You need to receive it as an array in order to obtain what you want. Use the fourth argument of [`$.get`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get#urldatacallbacktype) in order to specify the type, in your case JSON:

```
$.get('ajax/time_menus.php', { shift: $('#shifts').val() }, function(data) {
    ...
}, "json"); // <--here

// or shorter

$.getJSON('ajax/time_menus.php', { shift: $('#shifts').val() }, function(data) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: When I do this nothing happens. If I remove my json_encode($var); in my PHP page the alert shows Undefined

Comment: Install Firebug and see what is the actual response the browser receives. It may not be valid JSON. Or try `$.getJSON(url, data, callback);`

Comment: Tried those but no luck response is: ["04","00","PM","11","00","PM"]

Answer (score 0):

try working with json by setting the **type** on the $.get to "json" (by default it returns a HTML/XML response)